# Edit HTML in IE Developer Toolbar

Tags: html, internet-explorer, dom

Is it possible to edit HTML, add nodes, etc. using IE Developer Toolbar?

Answer (score 6):

Bring up the Dev Toolbar, select HTML tab, click the edit button. Find the mark-up you want to edit in the awful mess you're presented with. Edit then, when you're finished, click the edit button again to apply changes and return.

Nowhere near as elegant as Firebug but it'll do.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the individual nodes, but I can't see a function to add new ones.

Comment: If only someone would do a port of firebug to a native IE plugin.

Comment: You can add/edit attributes, but I don't think you can do much beyong that.  I just went to double-check that but for some strange reason my IE8 on Win7 brings up a non-existent window!

Comment: Andy E, what is a non-existent Window? :)

Comment: @Pekka: In my case, it's a window that adds a thumbnail to the list for the taskbar icon, but when you hover over it there's nothing there :-)

Comment: @Andy that sounds odd! Try going to `about:blank` first and then opening the tools.

Comment: @Pekka: Nope, not even after a restart!  Not sure how I've broken it.